# Execute a parallel flux after another flux has ended

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

BTW I'm still learning weblux;
I don't know if this is possible or I have the wrong approach but given this parallel flux.

```
Flux<String> enablers = Flux.fromIterable(enablersList)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .flatMap(element -> service.getAMono(string, entity, element))
                .sequential();
```

who calls a method that has a webclient request (service.getAMono)

```
webClient.post()
              .uri(url)
              .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(httpHeaders))
              .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
              .retrieve()
              .bodyToMono(entity2.class);
```

I need to wait for enablers flux's flow ends and process all the responses inside it, the reason is if one of them gives me error or a negative response i won't run this other Parallel Flux for blockers

```
Flux<String> blockers = Flux.fromIterable(blockersList)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .flatMap(element -> service.callAMono(string, entity, element))
                .sequential();
```

I though about "zip" method, but this one merge both response and is not what I want
If anybody could help me with this.

UPDATE

```
enablers. //handle enablers response and if error return a custom Mono<response> with .reduce
```

And if no error in the handle of `enablers` proceed to the `.thenMany` with the other `Flux`

Comment: If I get your requirement right, `thenMany` operator is what you are looking for: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#thenMany-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-

Comment: Ok I understand that thenMany will help me to call the second flux when the first one has ended but how I can handle the data from the first flux and if a condition fails returns to the client an error and the flux inside thenMany isn't called btw i forgot to add that i have to reduce the response to a Mono<entity3> I'll update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it by conditional `any` in the first `flux`, like this

```
Flux.fromIterable(enablersList)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .flatMap(element -> service.getAMono(string, entity, element))
                .sequential()
                .any(element -> *stuff here)//condition
                .flatMap(condition->{
                        if(condition.equals(Boolean.FALSE)){
                           return Flux.fromIterable(blockersList)
                                                   .parallel()
                                                   .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                                                   .flatMap(element -> service.callAMono(string, entity, element))
                                                   .sequential()
                                                   .reduce(**stuff here)// handle noError response and return;
                          }
                          return Mono.just(**stuff here);//handle error response and return
                 });
```

If there is another way to do this please I'll be glad you post it here Thanks, :D